# Finding line number

Tags: perl, file, count, line

How can I find the current position in a file?
I just can count total numbers in a file.
I've read about functions `tell()` and `seek()` but I don't understand how exactly to use them.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to find out? Line number or byte offset?

Answer (score 1):

When you are reading from a file (filehandle, actually), you can use `$.` to find out the line number of current input line. To reset the value of `$.`, you need to close the current input filehandle.

See [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-filehandles).

Comment: yeah actually that what I use, I'm asking if it's possible to do that with tell and seek functions

Comment: It is impossible with only `tell` and `seek`. To find out the line number of the line that current file position is laid in, you have to check the contents of the file from the beginning to the current file position byte by byte.